# Expecting Lambdas in RSpec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, lambda, rspec

I have a simple class:

```
class Maybe
  def initialize(value, maybe_klass = Maybe)
    @value = value
    @maybe_klass = maybe_klass
  end

  attr_reader :value

  def map(function)
    return self if value.nil?
    return maybe_klass.new(compose(value, function)) if value.is_a? Proc
    maybe_klass.new(function.curry.call(*value))
  end

  private

  attr_reader :maybe_klass

  def compose(f, g)
    lambda { |*args| f.call(g.call(*args))  }
  end
end
```

I'm trying to test it like this:

```
it 'creates a new wrapped function that does both of the functions combined' do
  maybe_double = double Maybe
  add_four = ->(x) { x + 4 }
  maybe = Maybe.new(add_four, maybe_double)
  composed_lambda = ->(*args) { maybe.value.call(add_four.call(*args)) }
  expect(maybe_double).to receive(:new).with(composed_lambda)
  maybe.map(add_four)
end
```

This test does not work- `undefined method '+' for #<Proc:0x007fdd0b269e78>`

I think the composed lambda is being evaluated before I need it to be, but I'm not sure. What should I expect the double's `initialize` method to be called with? Is this even the correct way to approach testing this class? I feel like I'm too closely mimicking the internals of the class with the `composed_lambda` variable, but I'm not sure what else to expect instead.

Also, because the function returns a new instance of the class we are testing, it's not really possible to stub that whole class - we'll end up trying to stub the system under test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that you have correct code, but you expect `rspec` to work different way. Here's the [issue about it](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/377)

`rspec` uses `===` to verify expectations, but in `ruby` when you use `===` operator on lambdas, the lambdas are called. Thus, when you pass a lambda into `receive(:new).with` method, `rspec` calls this lambda with an argument that `Maybe#new` method received.

For your case, I'd suggest using this cool feature for you tests:

```
it 'creates a new wrapped function that does both of the functions combined' do
  maybe_double = double Maybe
  add_four = ->(x) { x + 4 }
  maybe = Maybe.new(add_four, maybe_double)
  expect(maybe_double).to receive(:new).with(lambda { |composed_lambda|
    expect(composed_lambda.(4)).to eq 12
  )
  maybe.map(add_four)
end
```

So, you'll verify that the lambda that `Maybe#new` received is a composed lambda and applies the composition on the value. That's because you can't compare two lambdas until you call them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It looks like if I do `receive(:new) { composed_lambda }` the block just gets ignored, so it only tests that new gets called. Which feels like a weaker test as there's lots of ways that could pass without getting the behaviour I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can use variables from `it` scope

```rb
it do
    calls1  = 0
    calls2  = 0
    lambda1 = ->(x) { calls1 += x }
    lambda2 = ->(y) { calls2 += y }

    maybe = Maybe.new(lambda1, Maybe)

    maybe.map(lambda2).value.call(1)
    expect(calls1).to eq(1)
    expect(calls2).to eq(1)
end
```

Not perfect, but at least testing lambda execution.